# How to launch UWP app from the browser link?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am following this https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/11/15/deeplinking/ to support deep-linking in my UWP app.

Everything works fine if I click the link from some other app(my UWP app is automatically launched on the click of the link) but if I click the link from the browser, it stays on the browser itself.

I need a way to navigate to my app from the browser just like it is done in apps like Microsoft Teams etc

Microsoft teams example:-

[user receives email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zz3D.png)

[when the user clicks on the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3tt1.png)

Comment: What browser(s) did you test with?

Comment: Starting with the Windows 10 Creators update, supported links clicked in Microsoft Edge will launch the corresponding app. Supported links clicked in other browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer, etc.), will keep you in the browsing experience.

Comment: Please also confirm that you [Associate your app and website with a JSON file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking#associate-your-app-and-website-with-a-json-file) correctly.